# Craft CMS + Nginx redirection

Tags: nginx, configuration, locale, php-7, craftcms

I am using the latest version of Craft CMS with Nginx server. My problem is, in my site settings i setup 4 websites that are as below:

- German (de-de) [default]
- German English (en-de)
- Austria (de-at)
- Austria English (en-at)

Now my primary goal, for now, is to redirect any user to the default (i.e. de-de) website. So if a client requests `https://example.com`, he will be redirected to `https://example.com/de-de`. If I try manually to access `https://example.com/de-de`, it works.

I tried different solutions from StackOverflow and StackExchange but none of them worked for me. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($uri !~ ^/(de-de|en-de|de-at|en-at)(/|$)) {
    return 301 /de-de$request_uri;
}
```